# React Native/ Find and apply nth child of flatlist background color?

Tags: react-native, expo

How to set nth child of flatlist color validation in react native.

I have one for loop condition and I got the nth value of empty part in flatlist. How to apply nth child flatlist style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object of the callback in `renderItem` contains a property named `index`. It will allow you to do this.

You can use this to colorize per nth row. By using the modulo operator. i.e.:

Default background color is `blue` but it's `red` every 3rd element:

```
<FlatList
  data={YOUR_DATA}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: index % 3 === 0 ? 'red' : 'blue' }}>
      <Text>{item.message}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: how to set empty flatlist->textinput border color red dynamically after pressing a validate button?

Comment: That's a different question mate. Please, open a new one. But to quickly help you here: Link this TextInput's value to a state, on submit, detect if its associated state is empty and finally, set the border color style to either the default color when it's okay, but red when it's empty. If my answer helped, feel free to accept it. @ReactBala